# mysql sorting by desc and ignore alphabet

Tags: mysql, vb.net, sorting

I am making a chat that uses MySQL as a database. I am sorting the results of my query but its going down or up by alphabet and I don't want mysql to be sorting, I just want it to be like a description or something like that. Here is my code:

**Retrieval code**

```
Try
        MySqlConn.Open()
        ListBoxChatContent.Items.Clear()
        Dim Query As String
        Query = "select * from sysinfo.chatcontent order by chatcontent DESC"
        MySqlCmd = New MySqlCommand(Query, MySqlConn)
        MySqlRea = MySqlCmd.ExecuteReader
        While MySqlRea.Read
            Dim chatcontenttext = MySqlRea.GetString("chatcontent")
            ListBoxChatContent.Items.Add(chatcontenttext)
        End While

        TextBoxChatText.Text = ""
        MySqlConn.Close()
    Catch ex As MySqlException
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        MySqlConn.Dispose()
    End Try
```

**Submit code**

```
Try
        MySqlConn.Open()
        Dim Query As String
        Query = "insert into sysinfo.chatcontent (chatcontent) values ('" & LabelLoggedIn.Text + LabelLoggedInSC.Text + TextBoxChatText.Text & "')"
        MySqlCmd = New MySqlCommand(Query, MySqlConn)
        MySqlRea = MySqlCmd.ExecuteReader
        MySqlConn.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        MySqlConn.Dispose()
    End Try
    chatload()
```

As you can see I tried to do order by DESC. Now its going down which is good BUT when I submit text its sorting like alphabet by descending. I dont want it to be sorting I want it to be like a real description. Here is example how it looks:

> c text 3
>
> a text 1
>
> b text 2

And i want it to be like this:

> a text 1
>
> b text 2
>
> c text 3
>
> d text 4
>
> c text 5
>
> a text 6...

How do I do that? I hope you understand. I am a beginner with MySQL.

Solved the mysql problem kinda now the listbox is sorting,

Comment: I'm confused. You are sorting on the content field, but you say you don't want it to be sorted alphabetically. That is what sorting will do. Perhaps you want to sort on a date field, so the newest messages are on top?

Comment: Yes and no... I just dont want it to be sorted alphabetically i know you saw how chat looks thats what i am making a chat program and in chat text cant be sorted. I just want it to be like a desc. Just remove the sorting alphabetically.

Comment: Remove the ORDER BY clause, then.

Comment: I tried before adding order by clause its the same it goes up then not down and still is sorted alphabetically.

Comment: Ok it goes down now i solved it but its still being sorted,

Comment: Anyone please help. I need this solved this month.

Comment: I fixed the problem in mysql but now the same is in listbox. Somehow its sorting too.

Comment: The listbox is sorting the results? Is the `Sorted` property turned on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: i did mysql order by id soo mysql wont be sorting text. listbox had sorted option on true now its set to false. Thanks **Nate Barbettini** for solving my problem.